# Win 2-7 Plymouth Bootsplash problem

Tags: plymouth

I uninstalled the transformation pack, but the bootsplash didn't reverted back to default Ubuntu. T_T

I tried to do the manual terminal changing of it, and it worked halfway. The bootscreen when booting is still the (although awesome, I need to change) windows logo. But when shutting down or restarting, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change default plymouth theme manually. You can do this by typing `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` in terminal and choose the number, where the `/lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth` is(this is the default ubuntu plymouth theme). Now type `sudo update-initramfs -u` in terminal and you have the default plymouth theme back.

Comment: I tried that, to no avail, the bootscreen is still the windows animation, but when shutting down, it did changed.

Comment: Hm, try `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`.